# posting more than one line of text on fb status [Python] [Facebook API]

Tags: python, facebook, random

I started this project in the school holidays as a way to keep practising and enhancing my python knowledge. To put it shortly the code is a facebook bot that randomly generates NBA teams, Players and positions which should look like this when run.

```
Houston Rockets

[PG] Ryan Anderson
[PF] Michael Curry
[SF] Marcus Morris
[C] Bob Royer
[SF] Brian Heaney
```

I'm currently having trouble when it comes to posting my code to my facebook page where instead of posting 1 team and 5 players/positions the programme will only post 1 single player like this

```
Ryan Anderson
```

Here is my code

```
import os
import random
import facebook

token = "...."
fb = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = token)

parent_dir = "../NBAbot"
os.chdir(parent_dir)
file_name = "nba_players.txt"

def random_position():
    """Random Team from list"""
    position = ['[PG]','[SG]','[SF]','[PF]','[C]',]
    random.shuffle(position)
    position = position.pop()
    return(position)

def random_team():
    """Random Team from list"""
    Team = ['Los Angeles Lakers','Golden State Warriors','Toronto Raptors','Boston Celtics','Cleveland Cavaliers','Houston Rockets','San Antonio Spurs','New York Knicks','Chicago Bulls','Minnesota Timberwolves','Philadelphia 76ers','Miami Heat','Milwaukee','Portland Trail Blazers','Dallas Mavericks','Phoenix Suns','Denver Nuggets','Utah Jazz','Indiana Pacers','Los Angeles Clippers','Washington Wizards','Brooklyn Nets','New Orleans Pelicans','Sacramento Kings','Atlanta Hawks','Detroit Pistons','Memphis Grizzlies','Charlotte Hornets','Orlando Magic']
    random.shuffle(Team)
    Team = Team.pop()
    return(Team)

def random_player(datafile):
    read_mode = "r"
    with open (datafile, read_mode) as read_file:
        the_line = read_file.readlines()
        return(random.choice(the_line))

def main():
    return(
        random_team(),
        random_position(),
        random_player(file_name),
        random_position(),
        random_player(file_name),
        random_position(),
        random_player(file_name),
        random_position(),
        random_player(file_name),
        random_position(),
        random_player(file_name))

fb.put_object(parent_object="me", connection_name='feed', message=main())
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you fix your indentation so we know which blocks are nested where?

Comment: sorry my bad fixed now